# How to replace specific last string in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I am trying to replace the last word in a dataframe column if it is a specific text. Below is my code

```
import pandas as pd

lst = ['Main Close', 'Jon cl', 'Boon lose', 'Saint Cls', 'Brook CL','Smith clo', 'Petes Cl', 'Klein Cl.', 'Chuks Close']
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns = ['address'])

replace_values = {'Cl$' : 'Close', 'lose$' : 'Close', 'close$' : 'Close', 'cl$' : 'Close', 'Cl.$' : 'Close', 'CL$' : 'Close', 'clo$' : 'Close', 'CI$' : 'Close'}

for key, value in replace_values.items():
    df.address = df['address'].str.replace(key, value)
```

I used a dictionary to store the search value and replacement value. I am having problem as it is not matching the specific text ie

**Main Close** is modified to ***Main CClose*** but it should be ignored

**Pete Cl** is modified to ***Petes CClose*** but it should be Petes Close

What could I be missing. I have tried to use many other solutions from other question but could not figure it out.

Comment: `"lose"` matches `"Close"` as a regex. I guess you need `r"\blose\b"` instead to force an "exact" match with those word boundaries.

Comment: I tried your suggestion did not have any effect.

Comment: It did for me, interesting. `{'Cl$': 'Close',
 '\\blose\\b': 'Close',
 'close$': 'Close',
 'cl$': 'Close',
 'Cl.$': 'Close',
 'CL$': 'Close',
 'clo$': 'Close',
 'CI$': 'Close'}` is the dictionary I used with the only change being the one mentioned above.

Comment: Okay i tried this and it worked.  I will try using ( \\b \\b) in my code instead of the $ and see how it works. I want to use same style throughout the code.

Comment: Yeah `\b` asserts word boundary, you know `$` already I suppose. https://regex101.com/ is  a good website.

Comment: e.g., https://regex101.com/r/ugeDU6/1.

Answer (score 0):

Try `regex` along with `df.apply`

```
>>> import re
def f1(s):
    p = re.compile('^(\S+)\s+(cl|cl.|Cl|Cl.|CL|Cls|clo|lose|Close)$')
    return p.sub('\\1 Close', s)

>>> df['address'] = df['address'].apply(f1)

>>> print(df)

    address
0   Main Close
1    Jon Close
2   Boon Close
3  Saint Close
4  Brook Close
5  Smith Close
6  Petes Close
7  Klein Close
8  Chuks Close
```